# Realizar duas consultas no SalesForce gera valores Undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou realizando duas consultas no SalesForce. Porém, quando tento utilizar os valores recebidos fora do escopo da query, eles estão indefinidos. Segue o código:

```
var conn = new jsforce.Connection();
conn.login('email', 'password', function(err, res) {

    if (err) { 
        return console.error(err); 
    }

    conn.query('consulta', function(err, isWon) {
        if (err) {
            return console.error(err); 
        }
        var x = isWon;
        console.log(x); // Funciona aqui
    });

    conn.query('consulta', function(err, oppNum) {
        if (err) {
            return console.error(err); 
        }
        var y = oppNum;
        console.log(y); //Funciona aqui
    });

    console.log(x, y); // NÃO FUNCIONA AQUI
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A operação `conn.query` é assíncrona - a chamada retorna imediatamente, e os valores de x e y ainda não foram atribuídos quando você os imprime. Você precisa esperar que a operação seja concluída (quando a função que você passa como parâmetro é chamada) para poder usar os valores de x e y:

```
var conn = new jsforce.Connection();
conn.login('email', 'password', function(err, res) {

    if (err) { 
        console.error(err); 
    }

    conn.query('consulta', function(err, isWon) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return;
        }

        var x = isWon;
        console.log(x); // Funciona aqui
        conn.query('consulta', function(err, oppNum) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                return;
            }

            var y = oppNum;
            console.log(x, y); // Aqui você pode usar os valores de x e y
        });
    });
});
```

Você pode também executar as duas consultas "em paralelo", e usar um contador para verificar quando todas as consultas foram concluídas. Note que você precisa declarar as variáveis `x` e `y` num escopo que englobe todas as chamadas (por exemplo, na função de *callback* do login). Se você declarar, como você tinha no seu código original, as variáveis no *callback* do `query`, elas não estarão acessíveis fora deste contexto.

```
var conn = new jsforce.Connection();
conn.login('email', 'password', function(err, res) {

    if (err) { 
        console.error(err); 
    }

    var numeroDeConsultas = 2;
    var consultasTerminadas = 0;
    var x, y;

    conn.query('consulta', function(err, isWon) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return;
        }

        x = isWon;
        verificaTerminadas();
    }

    conn.query('consulta', function(err, oppNum) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return;
        }

        y = oppNum;
        verificaTerminadas();
    });

    function verificaTerminadas() {
        consultasTerminadas++;
        if (consultasTerminadas == numeroDeConsultas) {
            console.log(x, y); // Todas as consultas foram executadas
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Existe algum jeito de não ter que colocar uma query dentro da outra ?

Comment: Sim - adicionei esta opção na resposta.

Comment: Sim, funcionou, só tive que modificar algumas coisinhas. `consulta1done = true` não foi utilizada e as variáveis `numeroDeConsultas, consultasTerminadas` tiveram que ser declaras globalmente.